# Normal map on mirrored model

Tags: mirror, normal-map

I have mirror model, that I made to save the size of textures. But in testing I see, that part of model, that must be flat, has a visible seams:

[image]

**Normal map is configured to non-color, so it isn't a problem.**

The problem, as I see, that there is no color in RGB that corresponds to `0.5, 0.5, 1`. `#8080ff` is bigger than this value, about `0.503, 0.503, 1` and `#7f7fff` is less (about `0.498, 0.498, 1`)

So now I found only one method to solve this problem - create a mask and mix them this way:

[image]
*Less then value is 0.00001*

So **is there a suitable  method for using normal map on a mirror model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a great shame 128 isn't half of 255.

This isn't an answer to your question, but it does what you do to fix it without having to construct a second map as a mask.

[image: Left: direct connection of normal map. Right: after correction]

This node tree compares the map-encoded normal to (0,0,1), and if it's close enough, sets it to (0,0,1)

[image]

How close 'close enough' is, is set in the 'Less Than' node. The color in the 'Color' node is RGBA 0,0,1,0. (Is there a better way of entering a fixed vector?)

Comment: Could you extend the answer to include the values in the 2nd vecotr of the *dot product* node?

Comment: @Leander   Well spotted, and thank you. I think that tree must have come from  some half-cocked save of the Blend file - it's not what I meant at all. Funnily enough, it worked! But because I don't know why, I don't care.